# Importing csv file into firebird database

Tags: c#, csv, firebird

I'm writing a C# application that use a firebird database. I have to fill the database with data stored in csv file. Can you tell my easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Filehelpers to import the CSV data, then push it into the Firebird database using plain ADO.NET or your favorite ORM. But I'm almost certain Firebird itself will have a way of directly importing CSV data. Still, Google FileHelpers. It's a great library for processing delimited text.